# INET Omnet++ (Aggregation test)

Tags: wireless

I simulated an aggregation test in two scenarios: without aggregation, and with aggregation, but I got the same result. Why?

The aggregation test simulation was performed in INET (omnet++).

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more details on your configuration and the tests you performed, without that it's impossible to answer this quetsion.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean switch interface aggregation (LAG, etherchannel, etc.), then you need to understand that you will get the same results in performance per flow. If you are testing a single flow, then you should get the same results. It is only in *aggregate* with multiple flow where you will see increased throughput.

You really don't want a single flow spread across multiple connections because you will increase lost and out-of-order packet delivery. That can completely kill real-time traffic like VoIP, and it causes problems with TCP because it must reorder packets that are received out of order.

Your aggregation has a hashing algorithm that determines which flow gets which link in the aggregation, but all the traffic for a single flow will use the same link. An example is that the algorithm will hash based on the source and destination MAC and IP addresses. That means all traffic with the same source and destination MAC and IP addresses will use the same link of the aggregation.